# Yii2 WHERE IN query

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

The following active record WHERE IN query does not work. According to the docs this should work:

```
$data = $dropDownData->find()
                    ->select('country, country_text')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->WHERE(['in', 'server', $servers]);

$listData = ArrayHelper::map($data,'country', 'country_text');
```

The sql equivalent is :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT country, country_text 
          FROM `dropDownData` 
          WHERE server IN ({$servers})";
```

$servers just contains a string 1,2,4

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $server is a string  or is an array ???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on Yii2 documentation `$servers` should be an array not a string.

> in: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression. Operand 2 can be
>   either an array or a Query object.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#operator-format

Try using a proper array:

```
  $servers = [1,2,4]
  $data = $dropDownData->find()
                      ->select('country, country_text')
                      ->distinct()
                      ->WHERE(['in', 'server',[1,2,4]]);
```

or

```
  $data = $dropDownData->find()
                      ->select('country, country_text')
                      ->distinct()
                      ->WHERE(['in', 'server', $servers]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use array variable

```
$servers = [1,2,4];
```